# ¿Me pueden explicar cómo funcionan las dos funciones de PHP que generan código HTML y agrega clases CSS?

Tags: php, php7

He estudiado cierta parte del código. Entendiendo que el `bucle for`, `for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)` genera 10 elementos `li` partiendo desde un inicio de `0` hasta `9`. Penosamente es lo único que he logrado entender.

Me pueden explicar:

- ¿Qué hace la primera `function`? ¿Qué formula emplea, en qué sentido y en qué se basa su fórmula aritmética `(($value/0.5)-1);`?
- En la segunda `funtion` los dos `if` (`if($i<=$step)` y `if($i%2 == 0)`) ¿Qué control emplean y cómo añaden los estilos de las clases `CSS` `active` y `left`?

## Código

```
function step_max($value){
    // step from 0
    return (($value/0.5)-1);
}

function print_html($value){
    $html="";
    $step = step_max($value);
    $html ='<ul class="menu">';
    for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
        $class = '';
        if($i<=$step)  $class = ' active';
        if($i%2 == 0) $class .= ' left';
        $html .= '<li class="menu_item'. $class.'" data-index="'.$i.'"></li>';
    }

    $html .='</ul>';
    return $html;

}

echo print_html(3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te lo explico en tu código, cualquier duda hazmela saber.

```
function step_max($value){
    // step from 0
    return (($value/0.5)-1);
}

function print_html($value){ //Se crea una funcion llamada print_html
    //donde tiene como parametro $value y este parametro(variable) puede ser
    //utilizado en toda la función, incluso llamando a otras funciones.

    $html=""; //Crea un string vacio donde ira guardando el HTML.
    $step = step_max($value); //Manda a llamar la función step_max
    //y pone el mismo valor del parametro dentro de este.
    $html ='<ul class="menu">'; //El string vacio, ya no lo esta.
    //Se pone antes, para simular la generación de HTML, ya que si se 
    //mete adentro del ciclo, generaria muchas etiquetas UL.

    //Entramos al ciclo
    for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
        $class = ''; //Se crea un string vacio donde ira la clase.
        //En PHP, si solo pondrás una linea, no es necesario poner {}
        //El if de abajo de tu código es lo mismo que poner:
        //if($i = 0) { echo 'Test'; }
        //El ciclo va dando 'vueltas', una vez que detecte que el valor de $i 
        //sea menor o igual que el valor de $step, asignará a 
        //la variable un string 'active' (el cual es una clase).
        if($i<=$step)  $class = ' active';
        //Si el ciclo encuentra que no hay residuo en su numero,
        //concatenara a la variable $class un string 'left'.
        if($i%2 == 0) $class .= ' left';
        //Concatenara a nuestra variable $html, las etiquetas li,
        //y nuestra variable $class, tendrá nuevas clases y nuestro data-index tendrá el número del ciclo.
        $html .= '<li class="menu_item'. $class.'" data-index="'.$i.'"></li>';
    }
    //Concatena y cierra nuestro html
    $html .='</ul>';
    //Retorna el html
    return $html;

}

echo print_html(3);
```

Comment: Has detallado todo el código :) y la primera function, ese calculo aritmetico amigo?

Comment: Realmente no entiendo el sentido de esa función pero su funcionalidad es ir añadiendo la clase .active, en las etiquetas <li> si la condición se cumple.

Answer (score 1):

La función `step_max($value)` devuelve el valor pasado en `$value` después de haberlo dividido por `0,5` y a ese resultado haberle restado `1`. Si el valor pasado es `1` la operación sería la siguiente:

```
1/0,5 = 2
2-1 = 1
devuelve 1
```

En la función `print_html($value)` el `if($i<=$step)`, es decir, que si el valor de `$i` en cada momento del bucle es inferior o igual al valor de la variable `$step` (calculada por la función `step_max($value)`) le asigna a la variable `$class` la cadena `' active'`.

El siguiente `if($i%2 == 0)` valida que `$i` sea un número par, es decir, que al dividir `$i` entre `2` tenga resto `0`. Si esto se cumple se añade a la variable `$class` su propio valor más la cadena `' left'`. En caso de cumplirse las dos condiciones la variable `$class` acabaría teniendo `' active left'`.

El operador `=` asigna un valor a una variable cambiando el que ya tenía si fuera el caso. El operador `.=` añade un valor a otro ya existente.

Verás que al inicio del bucle se limpia la variable `$class`.  En mi opinión esta linea `if($i<=$step)  $class = ' active'`; debería quedar así: `if($i<=$step)  $class = 'active';`

Cuatro enlaces interesantes del manual de php para entender estas condicionales:

[Operadores aritméticos de php](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

[Operadores de comparación de php](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php)

[Operadores de asignación de php](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.assignment.php)

[Operadores php](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.php)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hace la primera funcion es calcular un valor pongamos como ejemplo que la variable $value que entra por parametro es = 5 entonces el codigo se veria asi:

```
function step_max(5){
// step from 0
return ((5/0.5)-1);
}
```

Por lo tanto lo que retorna es un numero que seria el siguiente 9.

En la segunda funcion el primer if indica que si la variable $i es menor o igual a la variable $step (que en este caso se declara como el resultado de la funcion step_max, o sea "9"), se declara la variable $class como 'active'.

En el segundo if el operador "%" es el modular, por lo que es el resto de la division de la variable $i entre 2. Y este declara la variable $class como 'left'

Answer (score 0):

Este código genera deuna lista de 10 elementos en `html` marcando los que son menores al  "doble - 1" del número dado como `class="active"`y a los que son "pares" como `class="left"`

Empieza a ejecutarse en la última línea que invoca a la función `print_html(3)`

Fíjate que esta función recibe como parámetro el número 3. Este número será el que reciba la función `step_max($value)` que calculará el doble del valor dado y le sumará 1. Lo hace dividiendo el valor entre 0.5 que equivale a multiplicar por 2.

El valor calculado es recogido por la variable `$step` que se comparará con `$i` y esto responde a ¿qué hace el primer if? se asegura que el iterador `$i`sea menor o igual a `$let`(recuerda que `$let`contiene el doble menos uno del valor que se ha introducido en la función `print_html()`.

El segundo `if` hace la operación del módulo que devuelve el resto de la división entre los números. En este caso lo utiliza para saber si el valor de `$i`es un valor par.